# sub pages redirecting to parent page in 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I have to redirect `www.abcd.com/aaa` AND `www.abcd.com/aaa/` to `www.abcd.com/aaa.html`

I have written following rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(aaa)/?[^(.html)]
RewriteRule ^ /aaa.html? [R=301,L]
```

It is working fine, but when i hit `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb.html` OR `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb` OR `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb/` it redirect me to `www.abcd.com/aaa.html`

I have following page heirarchey

`www.abcd.com/aaa.html`
`www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb.html`
`www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb/ccc.html`

When i write `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb` OR `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb/` it should go to `www.abcd.com/aaa/bbb.html` and so on.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /aaa [NC]
RewriteRule ^aaa/?$ /aaa.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But Anubhava, when i hit www.abcd.com/aaa or www.abcd.com/aaa/ it not redirecting me to www.abcd.com/aaa.html.

Comment: That's not correct. If you place this rule as **very first rule** in your root .htaccess it will definitely redirect.